# How to get contacts from only Phone device?

Tags: android

This code get contacts both Phone device and Sim Card.
Now, How to get contacts only from phone **without Sim card**?

```
String selector = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

mCursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
    selector, null, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Comment: there is no way to get only contact of phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Contacts from only Phone device (NOT from Sim Card)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769544/how-to-get-contacts-from-only-phone-device-not-from-sim-card)